# How to set repeat frequency in User Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, uilocalnotification, nsdatecomponents

Till `iOS 9` we write `local notifications` like this

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = pickerDate;
localNotification.alertBody = self.textField.text;
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitMinute;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

and in local notification we have `repeatInterval`, Now in `WWDC2016` Apple announced `User Notification` which contains

- UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.
- UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.

  ```
  UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger* trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggerWithTimeInterval:60 repeats:YES];
  ```

the code above will trigger notification after every minute. But can't set the date.

```
NSDateComponents* date = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
date.hour = 8;
date.minute = 30;

UNCalendarNotificationTrigger* triggerC = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:date repeats:YES];
```

the code above date can be set and repeat will trigger tomorrow at 8:30 not not after minute.

In iOS 10 `User Notification` how I can set date time with repeat frequency just like we can set in `UILocalNotification`?

I want to schedule `User Notification` tomorrow at 8:30pm and keep repeating after every minute just like the code I specified at the top regarding `local notification`

Comment: Hi all, I have the same question. Please let us know if anyone has implemented this functionality yet? **FYI:** The question is "How to set repeat intervals like everyday, every month, every minute etc for the local notifications in **iOS 10**". I am waiting. Thanks.

Comment: Found any solution for above problem?

Comment: Also very related: [UserNotification in 3 days then repeat every day/hour - iOS 10](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38380783/2415822)

Answer (score 1):

inspired by @Ramon Vasconcelos, I'm using the following code for setting up intervals and fireDate together

```
switch (interval) {
    case NSCalendarUnitMinute: {
        unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitSecond;
        break;
    }
    case NSCalendarUnitHour: {
        unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
        break;
    }
    case NSCalendarUnitDay: {
        unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
        break;
    }
    case NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear: {
        unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitWeekday | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
        break;
    }
    case NSCalendarUnitMonth:{
        unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
    }
    case NSCalendarUnitYear:{
        unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
    }
    default:
        unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
        break;
}
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:unitFlags fromDate:fireDate];
UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:components repeats:interval != 0];
```

Comment: This will set intervals, but not firedate.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 10 you can use like this:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:fireDate];
UNCalendarNotificationTrigger* trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:components repeats:YES];
```

it has the same effect from the iOS 9 code. To repeat you just have to use the components that you want to repeat.