# Repeat interval issue in userNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, schedule, unusernotificationcenter

I am working on the reminder app. For eg. if I set the timings of 05:25 scheduling it to repeat at every 2 hours, it is reminded at the interval of every 2 hours but it doesn’t remind at the current time i.e. 05:25.

```
UNMutableNotificationContent *localNotification = [UNMutableNotificationContent new];
localNotification.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Reminder!" arguments:nil];
localNotification.body = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:_getReminderName arguments:nil];
localNotification.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];

UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggerWithTimeInterval:60*60*2 repeats:YES];


UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:_getReminderName content:localNotification trigger:trigger];

request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:_getReminderName content:localNotification trigger:trigger];
/// 3. schedule localNotification
UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
[center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (!error) {
         NSLog(@"add NotificationRequest succeeded!");
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write your time on  `triggerWithTimeInterval` like

```
    UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggerWithTimeInterval: 05:25 repeats:YES];
```

Here **05:25** should be date formate.

And for your information you can't do customize repeat time interval you must use value of `NSCalendarUnit` like

[How to set repeat frequency in User Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37983437/how-to-set-repeat-frequency-in-user-notification)

If I'm wrong then clear me.

Comment: then how can i set  schedule for every two hours (triggerWithTimeInterval:60*60*2)

Comment: NSCalendarUnitHour is set only for every one hour i want get notification every two hour.

Comment: Yes you can't customize it like 2 hours

Comment: i already customise and it works properly but my main problem is i want to get notification from date picker date and time and also repeat after fire date

Comment: If you want to repeat like every 3 min. or 2 hours then dam sure Apple does not provide any property or API so you can set your repeat time there.