# iOS 11- User local notification which repeat every x minutes

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

In iOS 11, how can I implement a local notification which repeats every x minutes?

The repeating interval will be selected from the user. So for example let's say that a user choose to set a notification which will trigger tomorrow at 9:00 AM and from there it triggers every 2 days (or two weeks or 6 months or 10 minutes)

```swift
var repeatInterval = Bool()

trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: repeatInterval)

//Schedule the Notification
let identifier = titleNospace
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier!, content: content, trigger: trigger)
self.center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
})
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notificationRequest, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

With this code I can schedule a notification at a set date. I've been told that from here if I would like to schedule a repeat notification I should use a triggerInterval when the notification is delivered.
But how can I do so? How can I get the value of the repeating time (defined by the user) when the notification is delivered?
Shall I use this?:

```swift
func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification)
```

I've tried but it seems that it's never called.

I'm new to swift and I've tried and tried but it seems I cannot find a solution.
I've been able to manage the repeating hourly, monthly, daily and yearly.
If I would like to add a custom repeat though I really wouldn't know how to do.

Comment: Look on tutorials on how to use Notifications in Swift. https://www.appcoda.com/push-notification-ios/

Comment: @JonasSchafft these are push notification.... i was asking about local notification...

Comment: I'm sorry. I misread it.

Answer (score 0):

For your information you can't do customise repeat time interval like every 2 min, 10 min or Etc. you must use value of [`NSCalendarUnit`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendarunit) like

[How to set repeat frequency in User Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37983437/how-to-set-repeat-frequency-in-user-notification)

Comment: and it does not explain hot to set custom interval... i've been able to set hourly daily monthly.... i was looking on how to set custom interval... it does' have to be a way to set it...